# SQL Server : find a substring after the keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find the password on the line, I need to find a substring after the keyword "password".

The SQL Server database table contains these sample rows:

```
hello do you have any problems? Password: Qq111222 good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com
hello do you have any problems? Password: Aw654371 good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com
hello do you have any problems? Password: Zd354321 good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com
hello do you have any problems? Password: temporary password good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com
hello do you have any problems? Password: temporary password good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com
```

I'm looking for a way to find 10 characters after of the word Password, `substring` contains numbers and letters, is there a way to write this in SQL Server?

I using the following but got a lot of unsuitable rows:

```
select fields
from table
where fields like '%Password%[a-z,A-Z]%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `charindex()` :

```
select *, substring(fields, charindex('password', fields)+9, 10)
from table t
```

However, this may fail if your string doesn't have `password` word so, you can add prevention with `charindex()` or include `where` clause :

```
select *, substring(fields, charindex('password', fields + 'password')+9, 10)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the space on either side:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(8000);
SET @S = 'hello do you have any problems? Password: Qq111222 good luck  tel: 9-189309, email: sso@gmail.com';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@S,PATINDEX('%Password:%',@S) + LEN('Password:'),10);
```